# Bar Chart Merge 2 columns in a single bar

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have the following table, I want to generate a bar chart where for each year I can see a single bar, including both Cash and Credit.

[image: table]

Today I only see this:

[image: chart]

Link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2K-BiZLe0edtijDqINphbyjFM92xUhD-_DMh0VOwz0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: added above: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2K-BiZLe0edtijDqINphbyjFM92xUhD-_DMh0VOwz0/edit#gid=0

Comment: is this already solved ?

Comment: Is opened to everyone, I would like to still see each bar divided with credit and cash

Answer (score 1):

- you can either tick **Aggregate column A**:

  [image]

---

- or use **`QUERY`** to group years and output table directly from **`QUERY`**:

  ```
  =QUERY({A2:C}, 
   "select Col1, sum(Col3) 
    where Col1 is not null 
    group by Col1 
    label sum(Col3)''", 0)
  ```

  [image]

---

- or add the 2nd series and aggregate column A:

  [image: 0]